# Unknown CMake Command "slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule"

Tags: cmake

Currently I am trying to build PlusRemote from SlicerIGT, but I keep getting errors that don't make much sense to me. I downloaded SlicerIGT from GitHub [here](https://github.com/SlicerIGT/SlicerIGT), and I made sure to update CMake to version 3.2.3. The directory I am getting the source from should be fine. This is the error log I am getting:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule):
Unknown CMake command "slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Is there any way to solve this, or is there a better way to go about building PlusRemote?

EDIT: 
I managed to specify the minimum required version so now the only error I am getting is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule):
Unknown CMake command "slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule".
```

If anything, this is what CMake is reading:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(MODULE_NAME PlusRemote)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(MODULE_PYTHON_SCRIPTS
  ${MODULE_NAME}.py
  )

set(MODULE_PYTHON_RESOURCES
  Resources/Icons/${MODULE_NAME}.png
  Resources/Icons/icon_Record.png
  Resources/Icons/icon_Stop.png
  Resources/Icons/icon_Wait.png
  Resources/Icons/VisibleOff.png
  Resources/Icons/VisibleOn.png
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
slicerMacroBuildScriptedModule(
  NAME ${MODULE_NAME}
  SCRIPTS ${MODULE_PYTHON_SCRIPTS}
  RESOURCES ${MODULE_PYTHON_RESOURCES}
  WITH_GENERIC_TESTS
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(BUILD_TESTING)

  # Register the unittest subclass in the main script as a ctest.
  # Note that the test will also be available at runtime.
  slicer_add_python_unittest(SCRIPT ${MODULE_NAME}.py)

  # Additional build-time testing
  add_subdirectory(Testing)
endif()
```

Did I miss downloading or updating anything?

EDIT: Is [this](https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/blob/master/CMake/SlicerMacroBuildScriptedModule.cmake) what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlusRemote does not need to be built using CMake in order to have Plus run. Plus will start on it's own. Wish I had known this 3 hours ago.